# Do PlayStation Plus cloud saves automatically update?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

If I put game saves in to the PlayStation Plus cloud storage, will they be automatically updated if I play more of the game and save again? Or would I have to remember to keep updating the cloud saves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, they do automatically update. This feature was introduced in firmware update 3.70 which is super cool :)

> **[Source](http://www.engadget.com/2011/08/10/ps3-firmware-update-v3-70-adds-auto-save-cloud-storage-for-subsc/)**
>
> and **[one](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/08/09/ps3-system-software-update-v3-70/)** or **[two](http://uk.gamespot.com/news/ps-6328239)** more, just to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The playstation blog has a breakdown of the firmware release that included cloud auto saves.

http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/08/09/ps3-system-software-update-v3-70/